# Writing DRY Code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dry

I am really new to development, and I am re-writing the Battleship game from Codecademy to be 2 players. I am really struggling through this one, but I feel like it has been a good exercise, so far. I am wanting to maintain good OOP and DRY principles. I have a problem, though. I am trying to pass user input to create objects, and I had to create a two similar definitions to accomplish my goal. I have only written part of the program, and I have been testing as much as possible. To see my concern, check out get_name1 and get_name2 below:

```
 from random import randint


 class Person(object):

     def __init__(self, name, turn):
         self.name = name
         self.turn = turn


     def get_name1():
         while 1:
             name = input("What is the name of Player 1? ")
             if name.isalpha() == False:
                 print("\nPlease share your name with me.\n")
             else:
                 print("\nNice to meet you %s. It will be fun to play Battleship!\n" % name)
                 return name
                 break

     def get_name2():
         while 1:
             name = input("What is the name of Player 2? ")
             if name.isalpha() == False:
                 print("\nPlease share your name with me.\n")
             else:
                 print("\nNice to meet you %s. It will be fun to play Battleship!\n" % name)
                 return name
                 break



 Player1 = Person(Person.get_name1(), 1)
 Player2 = Person(Person.get_name2(), 2)

 print("Welcome to Battleship, %s!" % Player1.name)
 print("You will take turn %s.\n" % Player1.turn)
 print("Welcome to Battleship, %s!" % Player2.name)
 print("You will take turn %s.\n" % Player2.turn)
```

Is there a way to consolidate get_name1 and get_name2 into one function while keeping the unique input lines of "What is the name of Player 1?" and "What is the name of Player 2?" and still pass the unique inputs to two different class objects?

Comment: You probably also want to make get_name() an instance method rather than a class method.

Comment: For a start you could code the number of the player (1/2) in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best, use a classmethod to create a person with name in one turn:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, turn):
        self.name = name
        self.turn = turn

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, turn):
        while True:
            name = input("What is the name of Player %d? " % turn)
            if name.isalpha():
                break;
            print("\nPlease share your name with me.\n")
        print("\nNice to meet you %s. It will be fun to play Battleship!\n" % name)
        return cls(name, turn)

Player1 = Person.create(1)
Player2 = Person.create(2)

print("Welcome to Battleship, %s!" % Player1.name)
print("You will take turn %s.\n" % Player1.turn)
```

Comment: Daniel,

I liked  your code the best, because a create() method is cleaner than a get_name() method. I just have one question: How are you using "cls" in the method? Is that similar to passing "self"?

Also, I get this error when I run your code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KC\Documents\Programming\Python3\Battleship Game Two Player Build -- OOP.py", line 21, in <module>
    Player1 = Person.create("1")
TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'turn'

Comment: classmethods are called implicitly with the class as first argument. Similarly as `self`, the instance, this argument is named `cls`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the elaboration.

Comment: It's working now. The @classmethod seemed to fix it. Thanks for helping this newbie!

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_name(name_str):
         while 1:
             name = input("What is the name of %s? " % name_str)
             if name.isalpha() == False:
                 print("\nPlease share your name with me.\n")
             else:
                 print("\nNice to meet you %s. It will be fun to play Battleship!\n" % name)
                 return name
                 break

Player1 = Person(Person.get_name('Player 1'), 1)
Player2 = Person(Person.get_name('Player 2'), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

So the only difference between the two functions is the player number? Then pass the player number as a parameter to the function and use string formatting for the prompt.

```
def get_name(player_number):
    prompt = 'What is the name of Player {}? '.format(player_number)
    while True:
        name = input(prompt)
        # rest of code goes here..
```

In general when you find you have two functions that are nearly identical, you look for what is different, make that a variable, and pass the variable as a parameter. Then you only have one function which is modified by its parameters.